# Tabs without fragment displays

Tags: java, android

I need to create scrollable tabs at the top of my application. The tabhost seems okay however I do not need fragments displays (as seen in picture), I just need tabs that have a clicklistener.

I just need tabs like buttons, and they need to be able to be scrolled horizontally and pressed. Any ideas on how or if this can be done?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use HorizontalScrollView to achive this

Below I am providing code snippet, alter according to your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic7"
                android:text="image1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Textview1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:text="image2"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic2" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Textview2" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:text="image3"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic7" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Textview3" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:text="image4"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic5" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Textview4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: So with this XML i will have to create my own buttons for the tabs?

Comment: @DRCodeTutorial you have to design it that way, it will look like tablayout and will have buttons, and then noraml way inilitaize buttons and give click action to those buttons

Comment: Thank you, that works great, perfect for what I need :)

Comment: @DRCodeTutorial my pleasure friend!!

Comment: @Mrinmoy well said

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived by using `TabLayout`
and set its **tabmode** to *`scrollable`* tabs

create a new activity with ViewPager Tabs 
and in TabLayout set its mode to Scrollable.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tabs"
app:tabMode="scrollable"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

refer this page for creating Tab activity with viewgager.[TabLayout with viewPager](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/)